# PostgreSQL Fuzzymatching Error

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I get such errors when using these functions, what's is wrong?

```
pgdb=# SELECT distance('foo','zoo');
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 1: SELECT distance('foo','zoo');
                        ^
HINT:  You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON
pgdb=# 
pgdb=# 
pgdb=# SELECT difference('foo','zoo');
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 1: SELECT difference('foo','zoo');
                          ^
HINT:  You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON
```

May be these functions are not installed at all?

Comment: `distance` and `difference` are not for strings, they are for geometry types (just as the error messages says). Why do you think they would operate on strings?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think he is referring to the **[fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)** module which has indeed a `difference()` function.

Comment: @ypercube: didn't know that, thanks. So in that case, the module must first be installed using `create extension fuzzystrmatch`